# Getting the length of two-dimensional array

Tags: java, arrays

How do I get the second dimension of an array if I don't know it? `array.length` gives only the first dimension.

For example, in

```
public class B {
    public static void main(String [] main){
        int [] [] nir = new int [2] [3];
        System.out.println(nir.length);
    }
}
```

See that [code run live at Ideone.com](https://ideone.com/un8OMe).

> 2

How would I get the value of the second dimension of `nir`, which is 3?

Answer (score 117, accepted):

*which* 3?

You've created a multi-dimentional array. `nir` is an array of int arrays; you've got two arrays of length three.

```
System.out.println(nir[0].length);
```

would give you the length of your first array.

Also worth noting is that you don't have to initialize a multi-dimensional array as you did, which means all the arrays don't have to be the same length (or exist at all).

```
int nir[][] = new int[5][];
nir[0] = new int[5];
nir[1] = new int[3];
System.out.println(nir[0].length); // 5
System.out.println(nir[1].length); // 3
System.out.println(nir[2].length); // Null pointer exception
```

Comment: +1 especially for the dangerous advice about non-rectangular (and by that I mean it's dangerous to make assumptions about your data, not that it's dangerous to use non-rectangulars). That has fooled many a novice programmer, and made a fool of many a non-novice programmer who should've known better!

Comment: so essentially the `3` in `int [] [] nir = new int [2] [3];` is dummy(of no practical use). Right??? or is it used to allocate 3 cells in each row - default no. of cols in each row ??

Comment: @KNU if you use that syntax which explicitly defines the second dimension to be 3 ... then you get that length for each array. The second part of my answer is simply pointing out that you don't have to use that syntax.

Answer (score 21):

In the latest version of JAVA this is how you do it:

```
nir.length //is the first dimension
nir[0].length //is the second dimension
```

Answer (score 12):

You can do :

```
 System.out.println(nir[0].length);
```

But be aware that there's no real two-dimensional array in Java. Each "first level" array contains another array. Each of these arrays can be of different sizes. `nir[0].length` isn't necessarily the same size as `nir[1].length`.

Answer (score 6):

use

```
   System.out.print( nir[0].length);
```

look at this for loop which print the content of the 2 dimension array
the second loop iterate over the column in each row

```
for(int row =0 ; row < ntr.length; ++row)
 for(int column =0; column<ntr[row].length;++column)
    System.out.print(ntr[row][column]);
```

Comment: Note this can throw a null pointer exception if the second dimension array hasn't been created; should check `ntr[row] != null` before printing.

Answer (score 3):

```
int secondDimensionSize = nir[0].length;
```

Each element of the first dimension is actually another array with the length of the second dimension.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a complete solution to how to enumerate elements in a **jagged** two-dimensional array (with 3 rows and 3 to 5 columns):

```
    String row = "";
    int[][] myArray = {{11, 12, 13}, {14, 15, 16, 17}, {18, 19, 20, 21, 22}};
    for (int i=0; i<myArray.length; i++) {
        row+="\n";
        for (int j = 0; j<myArray[i].length; j++) {
            row += myArray[i][j] + "  ";
        }
    }
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "myArray contains:" + row);
```

[image: Jagged array's contents]

Answer (score 1):

```
nir[0].length
```

Note 0: You have to have minimum one array in your array.
Note 1: Not all sub-arrays are not necessary the same length.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that the length is same for each array in the second dimension, you can use

```
public class B {    
 public static void main(String [] main){
    int [] [] nir= new int [2] [3];
    System.out.println(nir[0].length);
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember, `2D array` is not a `2D array` in real sense.Every element of an array in itself is an array, not necessarily of the same size.
 so, `nir[0].length` may or may not be equal to `nir[1].length` **or** `nir[2]length`.

Hope that helps..:)

Answer (score 0):

Expansion for multi-dimension array total length,

Generally for your case, since the shape of the 2D array is "squared".

```
int length = nir.length * nir[0].length;
```

However, for 2D array, each row may not have the exact same number of elements.
Therefore we need to traverse through each row, add number of elements up.

```
int length = 0;
for ( int lvl = 0; lvl < _levels.length; lvl++ )
{
    length += _levels[ lvl ].length;
}
```

If N-D array, which means we need N-1 for loop to get each row's size.

Answer (score 0):

```
//initializing few values
int[][] tab = new int[][]{
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1},
    {1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0},
    {0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1}
};

//tab.length in first loop
for (int row = 0; row < tab.length; row++)
{
    //tab[0].length in second loop
    for (int column = 0; column < tab[0].length; column++)
    {
        //printing one value from array with space
        System.out.print(tab[row][column]+ "   ");
    }
    System.out.println(); // new row = new enter
}
```

Comment: You may need to indicate specifically, how you get the length of an inner array.  And also, in general case it is advised to calculate length of current row `column < tab[row].length` as in Java multidimensional arrays are jagged, and the length of each row may vary.