# Best way to store and retrieve the distance between cities?

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

Hi I am new to Java so please using basic and simple Java methods that will help me quickly understand your idea.

**Problem**: I have *n* cities (each city has a unique names) and they are all connected to each other so that there is a distance between any 2 cities.

What is the best way to store those distances so later if I use name of 2 cities (since name is unique) I can retrieve distance between them?

I was thinking about using 2-D array but it doesn't seem like a good idea (possible duplication distance between A - B and B - A, also can't using city names) does it?

**Why did somebody give thumb-downs to this question?**

Comment: What's wrong with a 2D array (dist)? I suggest you give each city a number and then you can access the distance between city 'i' and city 'j' with dist[j][i]

Comment: Giving each city a number is a good idea. Thanks! How to solve the duplication problem? Also I need to use name of cities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two possibilities to add to your own Idea

**HashMap of HashMap** - heavier than 2D arrays, but provide ease of use, by city names directly.

Alternatively, make an **`enum` with the names of the cities**, and use the `enum` to index into the 2D array.

**2DArray of variable dimension (non rectangular)** - Each row can have a different size, store only half of the full matrix and derive the other half as needed. [eg of creating a non rectangular array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7367237/1520364)

Comment: Perfect! Will try to implement all your suggestions except the HashMap and get back here update the question if I have problems. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If the distance between two cities is just the geometric distance, you only need to store the coordinates of each city.

Otherwise, store the distances in a N*N matrix, and keep an `String[N]` with the names.

Answer (score 0):

Look in to the concept of collections in java. This should help you implement what you are looking for:

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html