# How can I make my code more efficient by using an array

Tags: arrays, image, graphics

I am a beginner programmer and I would like to make my code more efficient. How would I make an array out of the PIECE1 - PIECE 8 final ints and an array out of the image1 - image8. Furthermore, how do i call g.drawImage once and not 8 times using the said array.

```
public class GraphicalBoard extends Board {
    final int PIECE1 = 1;
    final int PIECE2 = 2;
    final int PIECE3 = 3;
    final int PIECE4 = 4;
    final int PIECE5 = 5;
    final int PIECE6 = 6;
    final int PIECE7 = 7;
    final int PIECE8 = 8;
    final int NO_OF_PIECES = 8;
    Image image1, image2, image3, image4, image5, image6, image7, image8;

    final int SQUARE_SIZE = 200; // The length (in pixels) of the side of each

    public GraphicalBoard() {
            super();
            loadResources();
    }

    private void loadResources() {
            image1 = new ImageIcon("picOne.gif").getImage();
            image2 = new ImageIcon("picTwo.gif").getImage();
            image3 = new ImageIcon("picThree.gif").getImage();
            image4 = new ImageIcon("picFour.gif").getImage();
            image5 = new ImageIcon("picFive.gif").getImage();
            image6 = new ImageIcon("picSix.gif").getImage();
            image7 = new ImageIcon("picSeven.gif").getImage();
            image8 = new ImageIcon("picEight.gif").getImage();
    }

    public void draw(Graphics g) {

            // Draw the board with current pieces.
            for (int row = 0; row < board.length; row++)
                    for (int column = 0; column < board[row].length; column++) {
                            // Find the x and y positions for each row and column.
                            int xPos = column * SQUARE_SIZE;
                            int yPos = row * SQUARE_SIZE;
                            if (board[row][column] == PIECE1)
                                    g.drawImage(image1, xPos, yPos, null);
                            else if (board[row][column] == PIECE2)
                                    g.drawImage(image2, xPos, yPos, null);
                            else if (board[row][column] == PIECE3)
                                    g.drawImage(image3, xPos, yPos, null);
                            else if (board[row][column] == PIECE4)
                                    g.drawImage(image4, xPos, yPos, null);
                            else if (board[row][column] == PIECE5)
                                    g.drawImage(image5, xPos, yPos, null);
                            else if (board[row][column] == PIECE6)
                                    g.drawImage(image6, xPos, yPos, null);
                            else if (board[row][column] == PIECE7)
                                    g.drawImage(image7, xPos, yPos, null);
                            else if (board[row][column] == PIECE8)
                                    g.drawImage(image8, xPos, yPos, null);

                    }
    }
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Using arrays will probably not make your code more efficient, but smaller and hopefully better readable.
Regarding the `PIECES` - you can init an array like this:

```
final int PIECES[] = new int[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};
```

I would also name the image files different. Instead of `picOne.gif` use `pic1.gif` etc. Then you can do something like this:

```
Image[] images = new Image[NO_OF_PIECES];
for(int i = 0; i < NO_OF_PIECES; i++)
   images[i] = new ImageIcon("pic"+(i+1)+".gif").getImage();
```

What is the `board` variable?
Be aware that getting the length of a n-dimensional array might be a bit tricky. [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7367218/getting-the-length-of-two-dimensional-array)

In your `draw` methode, I would use `switch-case` instead of `else-if` for better readability.
Also the calculation:

`int yPos = row * SQUARE_SIZE;`

can be moved in the first loop body, but i guess the compiler is clever enough to figure that out.

Comment: My board is a 3x3 array. Is it possible to be able to call the array of pieces in the draw method just once instead of 8 times. When I try to call the array of images[i] in the draw method, I get an error as well. Here is what i tried:

Comment: if you want the first image use images[0] etc. Why do you need the board anyway, if the information is just the current column and the row?

Comment: The board class has the information of what the number actually is in the specific row/column. This is a slide puzzle game so the data in the board changes. Here is what I tried but I seem to be getting an error because I cannot find the index of the PIECES and I can't seem to call images[]:                                                 `int unknownPiece = board[row][column] ;`
`int indexOfPiece =  PIECES.indexOf(unknownPiece);`
`g.drawImage(images[indexOfPiece], xPos, yPos, null);`